# NavigationController issue when picking image from gallery

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new in swift language. i have a 2 viewcontroller under a navigation controller. 1st controller has some views and we can go to second viewcontroller by tapping a button. In the second viewcontroller there are image picking button to fetch a image from gallery and show in imageview. whenever i try to pick a image and back to my app it will go to the 1st viewcontroller automatically.

I don't know whether the stack is automatically cleared or not.

Comment: The view controller stack is not "cleared" - the first view controller is always the same. But you need to write the code to tell view controller 1 how to reload its data - write a function in view controller 1's `viewDidAppear` to reload all relevant data (including the image). If you're already trying this and it isn't working, you will need to post your code for us to help.

Comment: it is solved cause i wrote in viewwillappear for custom tabviewcontroller whereas it should be in viewdidload. thats why it was reinitialized every time